# Requesting user input for character's stats

Tags: c#, events, textbox, runtime-error, return-value

[image: My Problem]

```
if ((ParseIsSuccessfull = int.TryParse(P1STRtextbox.Text, out result)) == true)//Try parsing the STR text box;If it parses successfully
{

    PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].Strength = 0;//These couple lines reset the value of strength initially 
    int SumOfAllStatPoints = PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].Strength + //Without these couple lines the user cannot enter their total number of points into this text field
            PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].Dexterity + PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].Vigor + // 
            PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].RedMagic + PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].BlueMagic;//
    P1RemainingStatPointsLabel.Text = (PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].TotalStatPoints - SumOfAllStatPoints).ToString();//Recalculate the remaining stat points each time the text is changed       

    PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].Strength = int.Parse(P1STRtextbox.Text);//Store the parsed value into PlayerOnes Strength Value
    if (PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].Strength > int.Parse(P1RemainingStatPointsLabel.Text))//If PlayerOnes Strength Input is greater than the remaining stat points
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have enter a number larger than your remaining stat points!");//Prompt the user to enter a valid number
    }
    else if (PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].Strength < int.Parse(P1RemainingStatPointsLabel.Text))//If PlayerOnes Strength Input is less than the remaining stat points
    {

        PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].Strength = int.Parse(P1STRtextbox.Text);//Store the STR input in an integer value
        SumOfAllStatPoints = PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].Strength + //Total up All of player ones stats that the user has the option to input a number for
            PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].Dexterity + PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].Vigor + //In this case STR/DEX/VIG/RM/BM
            PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].RedMagic + PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].BlueMagic;

        PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].RemainingStatPoints = (PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].TotalStatPoints - SumOfAllStatPoints);

        P1RemainingStatPointsLabel.Text = PlayerOne[P1ClassNumber].RemainingStatPoints.ToString();//Display the updated stat points in the remaining stat points label
    }
}
else if ((ParseIsSuccessfull = int.TryParse(P1STRtextbox.Text, out result)) == true)//If the parse is unsuccessfull
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter numbers only!");//Display an error message
}
```

Quick definition of the functionality: A player selects a playable character class, the inputs their level(All done in the "Class Select" Tab in the picture). After doing so they input their level. That level is taken and multiplied by 10 to give the player a total amount of stat points that they can allocate to their character. Initially TotalStatPoints = RemainingStatPoints. The user then goes to the "Input Stats" tab where they would allocate their stats. The value of their stats are updated everytime the user makes a change to the value in the text box.

My Problem: Everything works fine, but when I enter 3000(Which is my total stat points), the field that displays my Remaining stat points shows 3000 rather than 0. I guess somewhere in my code it messes up and sets the remaining stat points variable to 3000, because the Label that displays the remaining points is localized.

Question: What seems to be my problem here? Is there any logical advice you can give? Thank you for your time and effort in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

code misses the condition where Strength is equal to remaining stat points
i.e. use <= instead of <

Comment: Thank you. Wow, when I over complicate things I forget to look at the simple things and tend to create more errors. Silly me, thank you so much!

Comment: I would also recommend making the RemainingStatPoints a function/readonly property, could be part of the same object that holds the other stats.this could make the code simpler and you could avoid parsing the label text everytime.